# create spree extension unable to activate rails-3.2.4 - activesupport version conflicts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, conflict, spree

I'm a newbie to Ruby/Rails/Spree and am trying to follow [this tutorial](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/extensions_tutorial.html#creating-an-extension) to create a simple spree extension.

I enter this command:

```
spree extension simple_sales
```

and cd into `spree_simple_sales`

Any rails command I type now within this directory (eg. `rails -v`) results in this error:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1637:in `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate rails-3.2.4, because activesupport-4.0.0 conflicts with activesupport (= 3.2.14), actionpack-4.0.0 conflicts with actionpack (= 3.2.14), railties-4.0.0 conflicts with railties (= 3.2.14), activerecord-4.0.0 conflicts with activerecord (= 3.2.14), actionmailer-4.0.0 conflicts with actionmailer (= 3.2.14) (Gem::LoadError)
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:746:in `activate'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:780:in `block in activate_dependencies'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:766:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:766:in `activate_dependencies'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:750:in `activate'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:780:in `block in activate_dependencies'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:766:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:766:in `activate_dependencies'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:750:in `activate'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:212:in `rescue in try_activate'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:209:in `try_activate'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `rescue in require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from D:/Dev/Tests and Tutorials/rails/extensions/spree_simple_sales/lib/spree_simple_sales/engine.rb:3:in `<class:Engine>'
    from D:/Dev/Tests and Tutorials/rails/extensions/spree_simple_sales/lib/spree_simple_sales/engine.rb:2:in `<module:SpreeSimpleSale>'
    from D:/Dev/Tests and Tutorials/rails/extensions/spree_simple_sales/lib/spree_simple_sales/engine.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine/commands.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from script/rails:7:in `<main>'
```

What can I do to fix this? I am on Win 7, have used RailsInstaller to install Ruby 1.9.3. I have both Rails 4.0.0 and 3.2.14 but am using Rails 3.2.14 with Spree.

**UPDATE**
I discovered if i add `bundle exec` in front of rails command eg. `bundle exec rails -v` it works .. but any rails command without `bundle exec` generates the above error.. but WHY? And why is this issue only happening that `spree extension` generated directory?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is likely because the rails command you are executing is Rails 4, and the Gemfile and/or gemspec that you're using in your extension specifies rails 3.2.x (or vice-versa).

Try running the same command with:

```
rails _3.2.4_ -v
```

in that directory.

---

Also note, Rails 3.2.4 is quite out of date with several security vulnerabilities.  You should upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: i'm using rails 3.2.14 not 3.2.4, and this command `rails _3.2.14_ -v` gives me the same error. Could the error be caused by the command `spree extension` setting up the `spree_simple_sales` directory but somehow using rails 4 instead of rails 3.2.14?